# How to extend django abstract base model by inheritance?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I'm trying to extend my django *abstract base model* via inheritance, but django model's behavior that automatically sets `abstract = True` to `abstract = False` on any subclasses of  abstract models is bothering me.

So the situation is

```
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

Class TimeStampedModel(Model):
    created_time = DateTimeField()
    modified_time = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('created_time',)
        get_latest_by = 'created_time'


class RecordModelMetaClass(ModelBase):
    # NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
    pass


class RecordModel(TimeStampedModel):
    __metaclass__ = RecordModelMetaClass

    recording_model = NotImplemented
    recording_fields = NotImplemented
```

Where the abstract TimeStampedModel is base model for abstract RecordModel.

The problem is that *Django*'s metaclass `ModelBase` automatically converts RecordModel's  `abstract = True` to `abstract = False` when RecordModel is defined in import time.

Is there any way to turn off this django's behavior?

Comment: what is ModelMase (to be corrected in ModelBase, BTW)?

Comment: @Pynchia It's a metaclass for django.db.models.Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and this is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance):

> If the child wants to extend the parent’s Meta class, it can subclass it.

In your case:

```
class RecordModel(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta(TimestampedModel.Meta):
        abstract = True
```